Interpretation of between ... and

There is commonly a one-to-one relation between 'given' in contrast to 'new' information on the one hand, and theme in contrast to focus on the other.( A comprehensive grammar of the English language, section 18.5)

I'm not sure which and which the one-to-one relation is between.

Between given and new, and between theme and focus
Between given and theme, and between new and focus.

Which interpretation is correct 1 or 2?

Hi. It doesn't say anything resembling option 2.  The wording is quite clear: between A in contrast to B on the one hand, and [between] X in contrast to Y on the other [hand].  Are you confused by the ellipsis here?

Let's replace these abstract concepts with something more concrete:

There is commonly a one-to-one relation between heat in contrast to cold on the one hand, and light in contrast to darkness on the other.

We can simplify this further, and then add detail back in:

There is a one-to-one relation between heat and light.

That is, things that are true of "heat" are also true of "light." What kind of things?

There is a one-to-one relation between heat (in contrast to cold) and light (in contrast to darkness).

That is, the way that heat relates to cold, contrasting it, parallels the way that light relates to darkness.
Now, without knowing more about the context and intent of the author, it's possible that the elements in these pairs could be reversed, that the sentence could be rewritten as...

There is commonly a one-to-one relation between cold in contrast to heat on the one hand, and darkness in contrast to light on the other.

Maybe that's possible. Maybe not. Maybe the author's point was only about two things ("given" and "theme") and the way that each of them contrasted with another item.
So, the direct answer to your questions:

A relationship between two pairs is clearly made. That is, "between [given and new], and [theme and focus]." This much is clear.
A relationship between corresponding elements within the pairs also seems to be implied (though the nature of that relationship isn't really clear without more context). That is, "between given [as it relates to new] and theme [as it relates to focus]."

But anything "between" the items within the pair, like "between given and new," is not described as "a one-to-one relationship," but simply by the phrase "in contrast."
